# How to update state multiple times on same event using React useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was wondering if it's possible to update state multiple times in a single event. Say I have a form where multiple `inputs` may need to be used to update a single state based on some logic like the below example:

State defined in parent component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function ParentComponent() {
   const [state, setState] = useState([]);
   return (
      <ChildComponent state={state} setState={setState} />
   )};

export default ParentComponent;
```

State updated in child component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function ChildComponent(props) {
   const onSubmit = data => {
      if(someLogicHere) {
         props.setState(_ => [...props.state, data]);
      }
      if(someOtherLogicHere) {
         props.setState(_ => [...props.state, data]);
      }
   }
   return (
      //Form goes here
)};

export default ChildComponent;
```

When using this method, only the output of the first `if` statement is returned `onSubmit` and added to the state object. Is there a way to have the output from all possible `if` statements be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build the array first then update the state once, something like that:

```
const onSubmit = data => {
  let result = [...props.state];

  if(someLogicHere) {
    result.push(data);
  }
  if(someOtherLogicHere) {
    result.push(data);
  }

  props.setState(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback form of `setState` for that:

```
function ChildComponent(props) {
   const onSubmit = data => {
      if(someLogicHere) {
         props.setState(state => [...state, data]);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^−−−−−−−−^^^^^
      }
      if(someOtherLogicHere) {
         props.setState(state => [...state, data]);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^−−−−−−−−^^^^^
      }
   }
   return (
      //Form goes here
)};
```

That ensure that overlapping calls don't result in lost data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use multiple `setState()` in all if conditions instead create a combined update object and then merge into state

e.g.

```
const onSubmit = data => {
   const data = {};
    if(someLogicHere) {
       data['a'] = 1;
    }
    if(someOtherLogicHere) {
       data['b'] = 2;
    }
    if(anotherLogic) {
       data['b'] = data['b'] + 10;
    }
    props.setState(_ => [...props.state, data]);
 }
```